# Is Geralt a "Ladies man" in the books series?

Tags: the-witcher

The videogame series depicts Geralt to be a ladies man, bedding every tavern girl in every village he stays in.

Is this behavior also present in the books, or something that is introduced only in the games?

Comment: The game just gives you the option. Whether or not he's a ladies' man is up to the player.

Comment: @MishaR sure but does the Option match his personality in the books is what I was asking

Answer (score 9):

Geralt is a womanizer also in the books.
He was an handsome and fit man, and the genetic mutation that made him a Witcher also rendered him sterile, taking out this kind of worry in encounters with occasional partners. Also, many women in this series are emancipated and often hold position of power too, and were not relegated to the "lady" or "damsel" role more common in other fantasy settings.

Some examples of women that had some kind of romantic or sexual relationship with Geralt are [Yennefer](https://witcher.fandom.com/wiki/Yennefer), [Triss](https://witcher.fandom.com/wiki/Triss_Merigold), [Fringilla Vigo](https://witcher.fandom.com/wiki/Fringilla_Vigo), [Shani](https://witcher.fandom.com/wiki/Shani), [Essi "Little Eye" Daven](https://witcher.fandom.com/wiki/Essi_Daven), [Renfri](https://witcher.fandom.com/wiki/Renfri), [Lytta Neyd](https://witcher.fandom.com/wiki/Lytta_Neyd), [Mozaïk](https://witcher.fandom.com/wiki/Moza%C3%AFk), [Iola](https://witcher.fandom.com/wiki/Iola).

Comment: It should be noted that the women listed here were ones Geralt slept with in a 30 year period... as opposed to Witcher 1 where you can sleep with 20+ women in what is probably about 2 months

Comment: @Joe Huh, really? Was there even that many unique female NPCs?

Comment: @Mithoron Yes, really. There are some cards which are unique depending on the path you take, but you have the opportunity to sleep with at least 20 women per playthrough. Here's a list: https://witcher.fandom.com/wiki/Romance_card

Comment: @Mithoron That seems oddly put. The Witcher series has very many unique female NPCs. Females have an enormous presence is the story.

Comment: @MishaR My point is in Witcher 1 there's apparently possibility to sleep with, like, every encountered female character, while I barely noticed this side of the game.

Comment: @Mithoron Yeah, I also didn't feel like the game especially called for it, at least not outside his main romantic interest(s).  As I saw it, Geralt simply had far more pressing matters.

Comment: Witchers aren’t just sterile, they’re also immune to diseases and thus can’t transmit them.

Answer (score 7):

**Geralt is kind of celebrity and in-universe popculture figure**

Geralt's best friend and famous poet, Dandelion, uses Geralt's life as an inspiration for many of his most renowned ballads.

Colorised stories of Geralt's hunts for monsters and his on-and-off relationship with Yennefer are sang and read across all northern realms (we see one example of Dandelion's performance in the beginning of Blood of Elves, unfortunately I don't have my copy of the book available to post some quotes), making Geralt kind of both Clint Eastwood and Romeo in the eyes of public. Many characters refer to him as "legendary White Wolf".

What is more, in the romance ballads describe Yennefer as the bad one, with the heart of obsidian (beginning of the Blood of the Elves again), therefore describing Geralt as amazing, but hurt lover.

Answering the question, it's not like Geralt is wondering around and seducing

> every tavern girl in every village

It's rather that his celebrity status combined with his attractiveness make him target of many advances. On the other hand, some characters seduce Geralt to manipulate him, for example:

> Fringilla Vigo and Renfri

What is more, most of the relationships mentioned in @Sekhemty answer happens in the early books, before the main story plot begin (in stories and in the Blood of the Elves). As the story unrolls, we don't see much (but not none) of romance going on.

To sum up, while Geralt is getting some romance through out the books, I would not call him "ladies man".
Videogames strongly enhance this motive, probably because *sex sells*

Answer (score 0):

As far I have seen, Geralt is not a ladies man. He is a Witcher, he lacks human emotions to some extent. He is not completely devoid of love but can seem somewhat distant.

Dandelion is a womanizer on the other hand, he is good-looking, dresses well, and has many feminine traits that can seem appealing to most, but he is a liar and expert manipulator. During a side quest, you discover Dandelion told many lies and promises to women just to enchant them. He is a performer and hanging with Geralt has made him somewhat popular so he exploits that, but underneath the surface he is just a coward of a man.

Geralt could not care less about fame or popularity, he is a man on a mission and doesn’t chase after skirts (except for Yennifer) probably cause of the Jinn. He also has needs but they seem to be driven by instincts rather than desire or lust. In the games you can play with him as you like, but in the books he is not into sex as most characters.